# Can you have more than one golden axe in Animal Crossing: New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

If I get the golden axe and then sell or give it away, is it possible to get another one?

Would I just have to settle with the regular or silver axe after losing my original golden one?

Answer (score 2):

Golden tools can only be obtained once per character. Reese will tell you as much when you're about to sell one to Re-Tail. You'll have to get someone else to give you theirs.

New Leaf has some item duplication glitches, so it might not be hard to find an extra in any case.

Comment: I bought one at the island for 9 metals... and I bought 2

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to earn another golden tool legitimately, however you can duplicate a friend's or persuade a friend to give you their's.